# Bot Framework - Facebook Messenger - no scroll down after button click

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger

If a user scrolls up the conversation and clicks over an action card button with PostBack or ImBack actionType, he hears a beep sound, but only manually scrolling down he will see the echo of what he clicked.

No auto scroll and no other visual clue that something was created at the bottom of the conversation.

How should I force scrolling down ?

Comment: Same for me. Did you find the solution?